# Invalid token @ found while passing email address in cfhttparam

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to pass two email addresses (JSON value) as follows:

```
 Line#91  <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="inpEmailObject"
             value="["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]" />
```

However, I am ending up with the following error:

```
 Invalid token @ found on line 91 at column 75.

The CFML compiler was processing:

    The tag attribute email1, on line 91, column 69.
    A cfhttpparam tag beginning on line 91, column 9.
```

How can I pass email address in the value field?

Comment: try swapping the double quotes around each email to a single quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to include the double-quote as part of the string you're sending, double it.

```
value="[""email1@gmail.com"",""email2@gmail.com""]"
```

Or, as Antony suggests, change one set to be single-quotes. This should work:

```
value='["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]'
```

Comment: Does Coldfusion understands JSON values as mentioned above in the value field or should I be serializing it first and then passing in the value field?

Comment: @john its a problem with parsing - the " is an argument name/value delimiter so your code was read as `value="["` and then there was some gibberish `email@gmail` in the `cfhttp` tag

Comment: I see. Do you think I should  `SerializeJSON` before passing it in the `value` field?